# Getting the cluster hierarchy using BisectingKMeans clustering

Tags: apache-spark

I am using the BisectingKMeans implementation in MLLib in spark to cluster some datapoints. I could get the clusters the given points belong to using the predict function exposed. However, I want to print the cluster hierarchy or the tree itself showing how the top down approach was performed. Is there anything that could help me see the hierarchy itself?

I found something here https://github.com/yu-iskw/bisecting-kmeans. But I am not sure how much reliable it is. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks